# How to avoid script alert in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to avoid script alert in my view page.That is when i users add script in text box or test area ,this script should display as script in my site's view page.

For example,

If user enter a message in text area like alert('hai');, this should display as alert('hai');. But now its alert hai in alert box, when the view page is opened .

Comment: `alert('hai')` by itself should not do anything, let's see the code in the view file you're using to render it.

Comment: For `alert('hai')` to do anything, as Wesley pointed out above, it would need to be in between `<script></script>` tags. If you just want to display it without it being parsed simply echo it into a `<div>` or even another textarea.

Comment: @eyaka1 users add it in <script></script> and it saves in DB like this

Comment: in that case refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop this from happening use the native php function '[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)'

```
$stripped = strip_tags($content);
```

Do this before you echo the data from the database.

Alternatively, if you want the  tag to remain but without it being parsed use something like [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$stripped = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $content);
```

Or better yet: [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

etc.